# How can find coordinates of parts of a big image to create an imagemap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have been trying to use **Jquery Image maphilight** plugin but can't becoz I dont know how to find coordinates of parts of an Image.The image that I want to use is http://i51.tinypic.com/35bsgw8.jpg

IN this image I want to highlight every block which has number on it, but problem is finding coordinates.Please help me

Thanks
Anks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alot of commercial software has this feature baked into (like Dreamweaver), but if you want to do it for free you could use an online tool like this:

If you just want coordinates: http://www.pangloss.com/seidel/ClrHlpr/imagemap.html

Or something a little more all-in-one: http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javascript script to get the mouse coordinate and record it.

Comment: but it would take  a lot of time as my image has large number of polygon area.can't i do it through SVG image file?